# Why can’t we register multiple base addresses ( sharing the same transport protocol ) with ServiceHost?

Tags: wcf

> We can register multiple base
>   addresses with Servicehost, as long as
>   addresses don’t use the same transport
>   protocol:
>
> ServiceHost host=new
>   ServiceHost(typeof(MyService),
>   tcpBaseAddress, httpBaseAddress);

What is the reason for not allowing a `ServiceHost` to register multiple base addresses that use the same transport protocol?

Comment: Are you self-hosting, or hosting in IIS or WAS?

Answer (score 1):

I guess because the WCF configuration mechanism would not know against which base-address to resolve relative addresses.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734786.aspx:

```
<service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service"/>
<!-- Not allowed, just for demonstration purposes -->
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/serviceOther"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
        <endpoint address="/test"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8001/hello/servicemodelsamples"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/servicemodelsamples/service"
                  binding="netTcpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is another relative address exposed at 
             http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
```

In the above example for all of the first, the second and mex-Endpoint there would be no way to figure out which "baseAddress" to use.